# ScalaFX multiple childrens

Tags: scala, user-interface, scalafx

***Backend:***
I have an observable collection of strings:

```
val list = new ObservableBuffer[String]
```

***UI:***
And I want to put this list after title in `VBox`:

```
new VBox {
  children = Seq(
    new Label("My awesome title"),
    list    //Doesn't work
  )
}
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
new VBox {
  children = Seq(
    new Label("My awesome title"),
    new StackPane{
      children = new ListView[String] {
        items = list
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Is there better solution?